# Using a Jacobian with MatCont

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a very large non-linear problem using the MatCont package. Due to the large number of dimensions, and the non-linear nature, I believe that supplying the Jacobian for my system to the MatCont algorithm will speed things up immensely. However, I cannot get it to recognise that it has a Jacobian to use!

As a minimal working example, I have modified the circle finder from the help documentation to include a Jacobian:

```
function out = curve()
    out{1}=@curvefunc;
    out{2}=@defaultprocessor;
    out{3}=@options;
    out{4}=@jacobian;
    out{13}=@adapt;
end

function f=curvefunc(x)
    f=x(1)^2+x(2)^2-1;
end

function J=jacobian(x)
    disp('USE JACOBIAN')
    J=[2*x(1) , 2*x(2)];
end

function varargout=defaultprocessor(varargin)
    if nargin>2
        varargout{3}=varargin{3};
    end
    varargout{2}=[0];
    varargout{1}=0;
end

function option=options()
    option=contset;
end

function [res,x,v]=adapt(x,v)
    res=[];
end
```

I then try to run this program from the command line using

```
[x,v,s,h,f] = cont(@curve,[1;0]);
```

However, the response is

```
first point found
tangent vector to first point found

elapsed time  = 0.2 secs
npoints curve = 300
```

Since I told it to output 'USE JACOBIAN' every time the Jacobian function was called, it is clear that MatCont is not using it.

How do I get the Jacobian to be used?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem! Seems I was quite close to getting it working. The below is a bit of a botch, so if anyone knows how to do it with options please post an answer also.

Firstly I edit the options settings so that when it performs the continuation it only locates the first point:

```
function option=options()
    option = contset;
    option = contset(option,'MaxNumPoints',1);
end
```

its fine for it to do this using numerical Jacobians, the first point is known very well in most problems. This is then called from a script or a function using the following:

```
[x,v,s,h,f] = cont(@curve,[1;0]);

global cds
cds.options.MaxNumPoints=[];
cds.symjac=1;

[x,v,s,h,f] = cont(x,v,s,h,f,cds);
```

The first line finds the initial point using numerical Jacobians, as it was set up to do. The continuer is then manually adjusted to firstly have no limit on the maximal number of points (this can be set to any appropriate number) and then the use of the user provided Jacobian is set to 1 (true). The continuer is then resumed with the new settings and uses the Jacobain properly.